# Is there a way to reverse the order of rows in a chart?

Tags: numbers, iwork

I'd like to change this chart

[image]

to the following one:

[image]

So, I'd like to reverse the order of rows. According to an answer on a similar question, you need to create a formula and put it in each cell manually to have this result. But is that really the only way to do this (rather simple) change? I have 3 charts I'd like to reverse and each of them has 3-5 columns and more than 400 rows. So, to put a formula in every single cell certainly is quite time-consuming (to say the least).

Btw., the numbers in every cell are supposed to be placeholders for words. So, selecting 2 cells in a column and dragging the window down won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I've finally figured it out. You need to number all your rows and then select the column which contains these numbers in the *organize/sort* sidebar. Finally, you choose *increasing* or *decreasing* to reverse the rows. This order remains even if you delete the column with the numbers.

Comment: Thanks. And how do you number them? Clicking and dragging the bottom corner of a cell like in Excel or Sheets doesn't work...

Comment: You need to first type in at least the first 2 numbers in the first 2 cells of that column. Click both cells by holding down SHIFT. Then drag the border down. Here's more information about that autofill function: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/03/27/fill-down-numbers-autofill-mac/ I hope it helps.